# Using command line to create AWS Elastic Beanstalk fail

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, worker

I tried to setup EB for worker tier by using the following command

```
eb create -t worker
```

But I receive the following error

```
2015-11-04 16:44:01 UTC+0800    ERROR   Stack named 'awseb-e-wh4epksrzi-stack' aborted operation. Current state: 'CREATE_FAILED' Reason: The following resource(s) failed to create: [AWSEBWorkerCronLeaderRegistry, AWSEBSecurityGroup].
2015-11-04 16:43:58 UTC+0800    ERROR   Creating security group named: sg-7ba1f41e failed Reason: Resource creation cancelled
```

Is there something specific to run the command line ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the eb command line buggy. try to use the web console. much more reliable.